# Using a pointer to change an object in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, object

Suppose I have multiple `Text` objects of various names and one `Text*` called `selected_text`. `Text` objects hold one `std::string` and have three methods: `std::string get_text()`, `void set_text( std::string )` and `void append( std::string )`. The third method appends a string to the `std::string` and does a bunch of somewhat unrelated stuff.

Everytime a key is pressed, I want to append the character associated with the key to the `Text` object that `selected_text` is pointing to. After assigning `selected_text` to a `Text` object, I execute the following code:

```
selected_text->append( key );
```

After that code executes,  I can print the value of `selected_text->get_text()`, which appears correct; the character associated with the pressed key was appended to the `std::string` returned by `selected_text->get_text()`. However, when I print the value of `my_text_object.get_text()`, the `std::string` returned appears unchanged; no character was appended.

I'm fairly inexperienced with pointers and this seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of how they work. **How can I use a** `Text*` **to change the values held within a** `Text`**?**

---

This might be relevant. I use the following code to select the `Text` object:

```
for( auto &text : Text_Objects )
{
    if( text.return_a_boolean_value() )
    {
        selected_text = &text;
    }
}
```

---

Okay this seems really helpful, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
for( auto &text : Text_Objects )
{
    if( text.return_a_boolean_value() )
    {
        selected_text = &text;
        std::cout << selected_text << " " << &text << std::endl;
    }
}

...

std::cout << selected_text << " " << &my_text_object << std::endl;
```

Will give an output similar to

```
0x258d250 0x258d250
0x258d250 0x60a760
```

Despite the fact the `my_text_object` is the only object within `Text_Objects`.

---

### Solved but still confused

So, I solved it by switching the type of `Text_Objects` from `std::vector<Text>` to `std::vector<Text*>` and modifying the for-each loop. I still don't understand why the original code didn't work. Am I correct in assuming that `push_back` adds a copy of an object, or the original for-each loop was being passed copies?

Comment: That should actually work fine, if `selected_text` is pointing where you think it's pointing. If you showed us the code that sets `selected_text`, as well as where you try to print `my_text_object.get_text()`, we might be able to help.

Comment: I agree, post the relevant code and we can be of more help.

Comment: Also, please clarify how "void set_text( std::string )" is not literally the answer to your question.  (not trying to be mean here, just looking to clarify what you're after)

Comment: Well, the related code is really convoluted and interspersed through hundreds of lines and multiple files. I'll add some related code to the post.

Comment: you do: `selected_text->append( key );`  or `selected_text->get_txt().append( key );` ?

Comment: @qPCR4vir I do `selected_text->append( key );` The `get_text()` method returns the `std::string` within a `Text` object. I wrote my own append method specifically for `Text` objects. I'm not trying to use the method that's part of the STL.

Comment: Are you inserting or erasing anything from Text_Objects?

Comment: @qPCR4vir I added more relevant code. No there is only one object within `Text_Objects` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Yes, `push_back` adds a copy of an object. That was the problem.

Comment: The `for` is OK. It works with a reference.

Comment: try to write self the answer

Answer (score 1):

I used a `std::vector<Text>` to store `Text` objects. This means whenever I used `push_back` to add another `Text` object to the array, I was adding a copy of a `Text` object, not the object itself, to the vector. All the code written in the question is correct. The problem is, the pointer `selected_text` modifies a copy of each `Text` object (which is stored in the array), not each object itself.

To fix this, I switched my `std::vector<Text>` to `std::vector<Text*>`, a vector of pointers to `Text` objects. Now, instead of adding a copy of each `Text` object when using `push_back`, I add a pointer to some predefined `Text` object. The `selected_text` pointer can be used to point to `Text*` within the vector, which points to a corresponding `Text` object.

Answer (score -1):

Because method `std::string get_text()` returns a copy of the object of type `std::string`  stored in an object of type `Text` then you can write the following way

```
selected_text->set_text(  selected_text->get_text() + key );
```

Comment: We don't know how the append() method is defined, but he did say that much did work.

Comment: @donjuedo He did not say that the class has append method.:)

Comment: oops. In my code, the append method does exactly that *and more*. The problem is I can't just use the one-liner because so much other stuff needs to be done. That's why I call the `append` method.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow:  He did, though.  It's right after the text, "I execute the following code:".  To your credit, I did notice no class specifier for the getter and setter, and wrote it off to editing for brevity.

Comment: @gragas You asked how you can change the string and I showed you how it can be done. I  know nothing about "other stuff to be done".:)

Comment: @gragas And your "other stuff" has nothing common with how the string is changed using a pointer to an object of type Text.